# When Running App on Android Studio (App Crashes) For More Specific Info Refer to Description

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-studio

ApiTokenActivity.java (class)

```
package nl.empoly.android.safetysupport;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;

import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.api.ApiApitoken;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.api.ApiAssignment;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.api.ApiClient;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.api.ApiClientLocation;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.api.ApiContact;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.api.ApiWarehouse;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.entity.EntApitoken;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.entity.EntAssignment;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.entity.EntClient;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.entity.EntClientLocation;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.entity.EntContact;
import nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.entity.EntWarehouse;

public class ApiTokenActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ApiApitoken mApiApitoken;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apitoken_activity);
        final TextView editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        Button login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String description = editText.getText().toString();
                new CreateApiTokenTask().execute(description);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                new DeleteApiTokenTask().execute(mApiApitoken);

                    }
                });

            }
        });
        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ApiTokenActivity.this,LogInActivity.class));


            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;


    }

    public class CreateApiTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiApitoken> {

        @Override
        protected ApiApitoken doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiApitoken.create(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ApiApitoken ApiApitoken) {
            TextView ID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TAG_IDtv);
            TextView Description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TAG_Dtv);
            TextView Token = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TAG_Ttv);
            TextView ExpiresAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TAG_EAtv);
            TextView RefreshToken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TAG_RTtv);

            ID.setText(ApiApitoken.id);
            Description.setText(ApiApitoken.description);
            Token.setText(ApiApitoken.token);
            ExpiresAt.setText(ApiApitoken.expires_at.toString());
            RefreshToken.setText(ApiApitoken.refresh_token);

            EntApitoken dbEntApitoken = new EntApitoken();
            dbEntApitoken.setSyncId(ApiApitoken.id);
            dbEntApitoken.setDescription(ApiApitoken.description);
            dbEntApitoken.setToken(ApiApitoken.token);
            dbEntApitoken.setExpiresAt(ApiApitoken.expires_at);
            dbEntApitoken.setRefreshToken(ApiApitoken.refresh_token);
            dbEntApitoken.save();

            mApiApitoken = ApiApitoken;
        }
    }

    public class DeleteApiTokenTask extends AsyncTask<ApiApitoken, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ApiApitoken... params) {
            try {
                ApiApitoken.delete(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void execute(String description) {
        }
    }

    public class ListClientsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiClient> {

        @Override
        protected ApiClient doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiClient.list(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ApiClient ApiClient) {
            EntClient dbEntClient = new EntClient();
            dbEntClient.setSyncId(ApiClient.id);
            dbEntClient.setExternalId(ApiClient.external_id);
            dbEntClient.setSearchCode(ApiClient.search_code);
            dbEntClient.setCompanyName(ApiClient.company_name);
            dbEntClient.setPhoneNumber(ApiClient.phone_number);
            dbEntClient.setFaxNumber(ApiClient.fax_number);
            dbEntClient.setEmailAddress(ApiClient.email_address);
            dbEntClient.setArchived(ApiClient.archived);
            dbEntClient.setUpdatedAt(ApiClient.updated_at);
            dbEntClient.setUrl(ApiClient.url);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesId(ApiClient.address_id);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesType(ApiClient.address_type);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesLine1(ApiClient.address_line1);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesPostalCode(ApiClient.address_postal_code);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesCity(ApiClient.address_city);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesCountry(ApiClient.address_country);
            dbEntClient.setAddressesUpdatedAt(ApiClient.address_updated_at);
            dbEntClient.save();
        }
    }

    public class GetClientsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiClient> {

        @Override
        protected ApiClient doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiClient.get(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ListClientlocationsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiClientLocation> {

        @Override
        protected ApiClientLocation doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiClientLocation.list(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ApiClientLocation ApiClientLocation) {
            EntClientLocation dbEntClientLocation = new EntClientLocation();
            dbEntClientLocation.setClientId(ApiClientLocation.client_id);
            dbEntClientLocation.setExternalId(ApiClientLocation.external_id);
            dbEntClientLocation.setName(ApiClientLocation.name);
            dbEntClientLocation.setPhoneNumber(ApiClientLocation.phone_number);
            dbEntClientLocation.setEmailAddress(ApiClientLocation.email_address);
            dbEntClientLocation.setArchived(ApiClientLocation.archived);
            dbEntClientLocation.setUpdatedAt(ApiClientLocation.updated_at);
            dbEntClientLocation.setUrl(ApiClientLocation.url);
            dbEntClientLocation.setClientId(ApiClientLocation.client_id);
            dbEntClientLocation.setClientUpdatedAt(ApiClientLocation.client_updated_at);
            dbEntClientLocation.setClientUrl(ApiClientLocation.client_url);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesId(ApiClientLocation.addresses_id);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesType(ApiClientLocation.addresses_type);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesLine1(ApiClientLocation.addresses_line1);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesPostalCode(ApiClientLocation.addresses_postal_code);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesCity(ApiClientLocation.addresses_city);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesCountry(ApiClientLocation.addresses_country);
            dbEntClientLocation.setAddressesUpdatedAt(ApiClientLocation.addresses_updated_at);
            dbEntClientLocation.save();
        }
    }

    public class GetClientlocationsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiClientLocation> {

        @Override
        protected ApiClientLocation doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiClientLocation.get(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ListWarehousesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiWarehouse> {

        @Override
        protected ApiWarehouse doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiWarehouse.list(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ApiWarehouse ApiWarehouse) {
            EntWarehouse dbEntWarehouse = new EntWarehouse();
            dbEntWarehouse.setSyncId(ApiWarehouse.id);
            dbEntWarehouse.setExternalId(ApiWarehouse.external_id);
            dbEntWarehouse.setName(ApiWarehouse.name);
            dbEntWarehouse.setLength(ApiWarehouse.length);
            dbEntWarehouse.setWidth(ApiWarehouse.width);
            dbEntWarehouse.setHeight(ApiWarehouse.height);
            dbEntWarehouse.setRefrigerated(ApiWarehouse.refrigerated);
            dbEntWarehouse.setTemperature(ApiWarehouse.temperature);
            dbEntWarehouse.setSprinklers(ApiWarehouse.sprinklers);
            dbEntWarehouse.setHazardousSubstances(ApiWarehouse.hazardous_substances);
            dbEntWarehouse.setImperviousFloor(ApiWarehouse.impervious_floor);
            dbEntWarehouse.setFireAlarm(ApiWarehouse.fire_alarm);
            dbEntWarehouse.setFloorHeating(ApiWarehouse.floor_heating);
            dbEntWarehouse.setFloorHeatingDepth(ApiWarehouse.floor_heating_depth);
            dbEntWarehouse.setInspectionFrequency(ApiWarehouse.inspection_frequency);
            dbEntWarehouse.setArchived(ApiWarehouse.archived);
            dbEntWarehouse.setUpdatedAt(ApiWarehouse.updated_at);
            dbEntWarehouse.setUrl(ApiWarehouse.url);
            dbEntWarehouse.setSurface(ApiWarehouse.surface);
            dbEntWarehouse.setClientLocation(ApiWarehouse.client_location);
            dbEntWarehouse.save();
        }
    }

    public class GetWarehousesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiWarehouse> {

        @Override
        protected ApiWarehouse doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiWarehouse.get(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ListContactsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiContact> {

        @Override
        protected ApiContact doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiContact.list(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ApiContact ApiContact) {
            EntContact dbEntContact = new EntContact();
            dbEntContact.setSyncId(ApiContact.id);
            dbEntContact.setExternalId(ApiContact.external_id);
            dbEntContact.setName(ApiContact.name);
            dbEntContact.setPhoneNumber(ApiContact.phone_number);
            dbEntContact.setMobileNumber(ApiContact.mobile_number);
            dbEntContact.setEmailAddress(ApiContact.email_address);
            dbEntContact.setUpdatedAt(ApiContact.updated_at);
            dbEntContact.setUrl(ApiContact.url);
            dbEntContact.setClient(ApiContact.client);
            dbEntContact.setClientLocation(ApiContact.client_location_id);
            dbEntContact.save();
        }
    }

    public class GetContactsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiContact> {

        @Override
        protected ApiContact doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiContact.get(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ListAssignmentsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiAssignment> {

        @Override
        protected ApiAssignment doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return ApiAssignment.list(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ApiAssignment ApiAssignment) {
            EntAssignment dbEntAssignment = new EntAssignment();
            dbEntAssignment.setSyncId(ApiAssignment.id);
            dbEntAssignment.setExternalId(ApiAssignment.external_id);
            dbEntAssignment.setType(ApiAssignment.type);
            dbEntAssignment.setDate(ApiAssignment.date);
            dbEntAssignment.setRemarks(ApiAssignment.remarks);
            dbEntAssignment.setArchived(ApiAssignment.archived);
            dbEntAssignment.setUpdatedAt(ApiAssignment.updated_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setUrl(ApiAssignment.url);
            dbEntAssignment.setClientLocationId(ApiAssignment.client_location_id);
            dbEntAssignment.setClientLocationUpdatedAt(ApiAssignment.client_location_updated_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setClientLocationUrl(ApiAssignment.client_location_url);
            dbEntAssignment.setArchived(ApiAssignment.archived);
            dbEntAssignment.setUpdatedAt(ApiAssignment.updated_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setUrl(ApiAssignment.url);
            dbEntAssignment.setWarehousesId(ApiAssignment.warehouses_id);
            dbEntAssignment.setWarehousesUpdatedAt(ApiAssignment.warehouses_updated_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setWarehousesUrl(ApiAssignment.warehouses_url);
            dbEntAssignment.setEmployeesId(ApiAssignment.employees_id);
            dbEntAssignment.setEmployeesUpdatedAt(ApiAssignment.employees_updated_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setEmployeesUrl(ApiAssignment.employees_url);
            dbEntAssignment.setStatusesId(ApiAssignment.statuses_id);
            dbEntAssignment.setStatusesStatus(ApiAssignment.statuses_status);
            dbEntAssignment.setStatusesCreatedAt(ApiAssignment.statuses_created_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setStatusesUpdatedAt(ApiAssignment.statuses_updated_at);
            dbEntAssignment.setStatusesUrl(ApiAssignment.statuses_url);
            dbEntAssignment.save();
        }

        public class GetAssignmentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ApiAssignment> {

            @Override
            protected ApiAssignment doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    return ApiAssignment.get(params[0]);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

logcat(error):

> 02-19 13:58:18.144    7472-7472/nl.empoly.android.safetysupport
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: nl.empoly.android.safetysupport, PID: 7472
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.ApiTokenActivity$CreateApiTokenTask.onPostExecute(ApiTokenActivity.java:98)
>               at nl.empoly.android.safetysupport.ApiTokenActivity$CreateApiTokenTask.onPostExecute(ApiTokenActivity.java:76)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Code Error at Line 98:** ID.setText(ApiApitoken.id);

**Code Error at Line 76:**
public class CreateApiTokenTask extends AsyncTask {

can someone please help me out I'm still a novice programmer :(

Any help would be really appreciate it ...

Sorry for not being specific with code :(

Basically when I run my application in Android Studio and during the execution of my app, the app is running perfectly. But when I type in the description field e.g. test6 and then press on the Create button, the app crashes ! and I get that following result.

Answer (score 0):

I think ID is simply null and you are calling setText() on it. put a breakpoint there and make sure.

If thats the case the problem might be elsewhere, post apitoken_activity.xml if you need help